# How to use 'terminated by' without using 'INTO OUTFILE' (using a client command)

Tags: mysql

To dump my table into a text file, I do:

```
mysql -e 'select * from my_table;' > /my_file.txt
```

but I need to dump the table into a text file where fields are terminated by a comma. so I did:

```
mysql -e 'select * from my_table fields terminated by ",";' > /my_file.txt
```

but it gives me this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near 'fields terminated by ','

MySql documentation [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select-into.html) suggests using 'terminated by' with 'INTO OUTFILE', but I can't use INTO OUTFILE because of some permission issues.
Is there any way to terminate the fields by "," when outputting the results using

```
mysql -e 'mySql query' > text_file.txt
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/select-into.html). The syntax isn't what you guessed. I won't repeat the syntax, you can read the reference documentation.

But I suppose you don't have privilege to do that if you don't have privilege to use `LOAD DATA INFILE`.

The other alternative is to output to tab-delimited format which is what the MySQL client outputs in batch mode, then transform the tabs to commas.

```
% mysql -BNe "select 123, 456"
123 456
```

That's a tab character between the numbers. Use your favorite shell filter tool to transform the tabs to commas. For example `tr` can do it:

```
% mysql -BNe "select 123, 456" | tr '\t' ','
123,456
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I meant I couldnt use "INTO OUTFILE". I corrected my question, but your answer worked. using (mysql -BNe "select 123, 456"| tr '\t' ',')